# Distributing data across month

Tags: php, math

Currently we store hours in a table that has a percentage field to distribute data across the week.

eg.

```
| dayint | daytext | hours | percent |
+--------+---------+-------+---------+
|      1 | mon     |     9 |    0.14 |
|      2 | tue     |    15 |    0.23 |
|      3 | wed     |     9 |    0.14 |
|      4 | thu     |     9 |    0.14 |
|      5 | fri     |     0 |    0.00 |
|      6 | sat     |    23 |    0.35 |
```

We are now adding a monthly distribution as well as weekly, so to calculate this I am:

1. Getting number of weeks in a month.

> $weeks = $days_in_month/7

1. Iterating through each day's percent and dividing it by number of weeks.

> $percent = $day['percent'] / $weeks

If my assumption is correct, this should distribute data across the month evenly. The problem is that it is consistently about 1ish % extra for the month.

If I enter 1000, I get 1013. If I enter 200, I get 202. Maybe I am just going about it wrong mathematically, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a problem in BODMAS

Comment: Could be rounding errors

Answer (score 0):

If your percent column stores data that has been rounded and is used in your monthly calculation as opposed to displaying rounded results that are stored accurately elsewhere then you will get rounding errors.

The example below shows the results for three weeks and the tables afterwards show the results using the actual data and the rounded data.

```
|Hours|Actual          |Rounded| |Hours|Actual    |Rounded| |Hours|Actual        |Rounded|
|    9|0.13846153846154|   0.14| |   10|0.15625000|   0.16| |    8|0.135593220339|   0.14|
|   15|0.23076923076923|   0.23| |   14|0.21875000|   0.22| |   13|0.220338983051|   0.22|
|    9|0.13846153846154|   0.14| |    8|0.12500000|   0.13| |   11|0.186440677966|   0.19|
|    9|0.13846153846154|   0.14| |   10|0.15625000|   0.16| |    7|0.118644067797|   0.12|
|    0|0.00000000000000|      0| |    1|0.01562500|   0.02| |    2|0.033898305085|   0.03|
|   23|0.35384615384615|   0.35| |   21|0.32812500|   0.33| |   18|0.305084745763|   0.31|
|   65|1.00000000000000|   1.00| |   64|1.00000000|   1.02| |   59|1.000000000000|   1.01|
```

Over the three weeks iterating with

```
$percent = $day['percent'] / $weeks
```

actual column gives the results

```
0.14343
0.22329
0.14997
0.13779
0.01651
0.32902
1.00000
```

whereas rounded column gives

```
0.146666667
0.223333333
0.153333333
0.14
0.016666667
0.33
1.01
```

Remember rounded results always go up or stay the same never downwards, so the error will always be slightly more than you expect.

Comment: I was so concentrated on these values that I didn't think about database values being rounded. This is probably the answer. I will check it out.

Comment: Took out all rounding and it is still off, in fact its even more now. Getting 1014 for the input 1000.

Comment: Without seeing code it is not possible to see what is happening. Are you taking into account weeks not fully fitting into months? Have you tried taking a month as four consecutive weeks rather than a calender month?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change my approach and go about it like this:

1. Get the total hours for the month by looping through:

   ```
   $total = $total + $day['hours'];
   ```
2. Use the stored hours instead of the percent to calculate a new percent using:

   ```
   $percent = $v['hours']/$total;
   ```

This approach returns the correct data.